# Access denied for Edit Page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint Page Mypage.aspx with page layout is MyLayout, and a user group MyGroup and have Contribute role in Mypage.aspx. 
When I use MyGroup account to edit page it show Access Denied page.
The I go to MyLayout, assign MyGroup as Contribute role, MyGroup account can edit MyPage.aspx without any exception.
The solution I found from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60699/user-with-full-control-permission-is-getting-access-denied-message

Anyone have experiences with this solution, could you please explain why I need to add permission to PageLayout/ MasterPage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, users should only need Read access to the masterpage/page layout to edit the page. However, if your masterpage or page layout has not been checked in and published, then the users won't be able to see it unless they also have Edit access (allowing them to view draft versions).

Make sure your masterpage and page layout are checked in and published.